# Read Access Violation on Tree Post-order Traversal

Tags: c++

I am implementing an iterative version of the postorder, tree traversal algorithm, but I get a "Read Access Violation" error when trying to run it.
Here is my code, can someone help me rectify the problem?

```
template<typename ElementType>
template<typename UnaryFunction>
void BinarySearchTree<ElementType>::postorderTraversal(UnaryFunction predicate)
{ // begin function
    stack<BinaryTreeNode<ElementType>*> stackedNodes;
    BinaryTreeNode<ElementType> *currentPtr;
    currentPtr = rootPtr;
    stackedNodes.push(rootPtr);
    while ((currentPtr != nullptr) || (!stackedNodes.empty()))
    { // begin loop
        if (currentPtr != nullptr)
        { // begin conditional
            stackedNodes.push(currentPtr);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->leftChildPtr;
        } // end conditional
        else
        { // begin else
            currentPtr = stackedNodes.top();
            stackedNodes.pop();
            currentPtr = currentPtr->rightChildPtr;
            predicate(currentPtr->key);

        } // end else
    } // end loop
} // end function
```

Comment: `currentPtr = currentPtr->rightChildPtr;` If that is `nullptr` the next line will cause an error.

Comment: I see two issues: you might be pushing a null `rootPtr`, and you don't check `currentPtr` before calling `predicate`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, predicates usually return a boolean value and don't have any side effects.

Comment: So, I have added a conditional that checks for null before calling predicate. It works, but now, it does not print the root node's values.